# UIButton inside of a scrollview isn't clickable

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have an app where I have a couple buttons inside of a `UIScrollview`. My view hierarchy is like this:

`-- UIScrollview
   -- UIView (content view)
     -- UIView
       -- UIButton
     -- UIView
       -- UIButton
     -- UIView
       -- UIButton`

But the `UIButton` isn't clickable. Is it possible that the scrollview is blocking clicks? I checked for:

- covering subviews;
- user interaction enabled = true (on all views);
- Scrollview Delay touch down = false;
- Scrollview can cancel on scroll = false
- The content view clips to bounds. Cutting off anything outside of the view.

but I couldn't find anything.Is there an issue with buttons and scrollviews?

Thanks :)

Comment: Make sure the button is fully within the boundary of its parent view.

Comment: Check the UIView debugger for overlaps etc.

Comment: Use the View Debugger. Or color every UIView in the story a different color so you can see them all. As you've already been told, if the UIButton is _outside_ the UIView that contains it, it will be visible but unclickable. Also, if any view down the hierarchy has its `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false`, the button will be unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the scrollview is blocking clicks?

Not inherently, no.

> Is there an issue with buttons and scrollviews?

In a word: no. Obviously buttons inside scroll views work just fine all the time. You probably use them every day in many apps that you use.

If *your* buttons are not tappable in a scroll view, that's because of something *you* are doing wrong. It is not because of anything in the nature of buttons and scroll views.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have overlapped a UIView with the UIButton. 
And enableUserInteraction is not required for UIViews, try disabling it.
Also check if you have linked the right UIButton event with the action method.